# Want to send details of ordered items with braintree payment

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, braintree

I'm trying to find a means of adding the details of what products were ordered in a payment so that the items purchased appear in the order on the braintree dashboard.

I must be missing something very obvious with this one, I'm guessing there must a 'product' or 'order' array that is sent with the transaction array but can't find anything that suggests that.

Cheers

UPDATE//

```
<?php
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '100.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient,
    'customFields' => [
        'custom_field_one' => 'custom value',
        'custom_field_two' => 'another custom value'
    ]
]);
?>
```

I can use the 'customFields' parameter to handle the order details but still want to know if anyone knows of a preset array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

There is no preset array for storing details about what products were purchased in a specific transaction. To make this information accessible from the Braintree control panel, you must use customFields.